# Downloading attachments to directory with IMAP in PHP, randomly works

Tags: php, imap, attachment

I found PHP code online to download attachments to a directory using IMAP from here. http://www.nerdydork.com/download-pop3imap-email-attachments-with-php.html

I modified it slightly changing

```
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $jk);
        $parts = ($structure->parts);
```

to

```
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $jk);
        $parts = ($structure);
```

to get it to run properly, as otherwise I got an error about how stdClass doesn't define a property called $parts. Doing that, I was able to download all the attachments. I tested it again recently though, and it didn't work. Well, it didn't work 6 times, worked the 7th, and then hasn't worked since. I'm thinking it has something to do with me screwing up the parts handling, since count($parts) keeps returning 1 for each message, so it's not finding any attachments I think.

Since it downloaded the attachments at one point with no issues, I feel confident that the area things are getting screwed up is right here. Before this block of code is a for loop that goes through each message in the box, and after it is loop that just goes through $parts for each imap structure. Thanks for any help you can provide. I looked at the imap_fetchstructure page on php.net and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I just double-checked the folder after typing up my question and it all popped up. I feel like I'm going nuts. I hadn't run the code since a few minutes before I started typing this, and it doesn't make sense to me that it would take this long to trigger. I have some 800 messages in the mailbox, but I figured since it printed my statement at the very end of the PHP that all of the file creation work was done.

Comment: You need to select an answer, Nick.

Answer (score 55):

This is perfect working answer, try this.

This Sample run properly and download all the attachments with no issues.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(3000); 

/* connect to gmail with your credentials */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'YOUR_USERNAME'; 
$password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM "abc@gmail.com"');

/* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
if($emails) {

    $count = 1;

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) 
    {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";
                $folder = "attachment";
                if(!is_dir($folder))
                {
                     mkdir($folder);
                }
                $fp = fopen("./". $folder ."/". $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

echo "all attachment Downloaded";

?>
```

About more, see the link

http://www.codediesel.com/php/downloading-gmail-attachments-in-php-an-update/

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad to help @GeorgeGarey

Comment: It helps a lot!

Comment: Glad for that @N.Dias

Answer (score 35):

this is final working sample

```
<? include('application.php'); 
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'XX@XX.com';
$password = 'XX';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'FROM "xxx@gmail.com"');



/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

  /* begin output var */
  $output = '';

  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);




    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);


    pre($overview);


     $attachments = array();
       if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
         for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {
           $attachments[$i] = array(
              'is_attachment' => false,
              'filename' => '',
              'name' => '',
              'attachment' => '');

           if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
             foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
               if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                 $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                 $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
               }
             }
           }

           if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
             foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
               if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                 $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                 $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
               }
             }
           }

           if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
             $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);
             if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
               $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
             }
             elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
               $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
             }
           }             
         } // for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++)
       } // if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))


    if(count($attachments)!=0){
        foreach($attachments as $at){
            if($at['is_attachment']==1){
                file_put_contents($at['filename'], $at['attachment']);
            }
        }
    }

  }

 // echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Comment: I tried this, "$attachments[$i]['attachment']" is always empty after imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1) - there's the name in the array, but there are no contents in the attachment key. why that?

Comment: could you provide the link to the imap class that you used

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code:

```
           $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $index);

       $attachments = array();
       if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {
         for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {
           $attachments[$i] = array(
              'is_attachment' => false,
              'filename' => '',
              'name' => '',
              'attachment' => '');

           if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
             foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
               if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                 $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                 $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
               }
             }
           }

           if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
             foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
               if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                 $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                 $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
               }
             }
           }

           if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
             $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $message_number, $i+1);
             if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
               $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
             }
             elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
               $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
             }
           }             
         } // for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++)
       } // if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts))
```

Answer (score 2):

**Some bug fixes and improvements on an answer that is perfectly working**

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $email_number);
$attachments = [];

foreach ($structure->parts as $part) {
    $is_attachment = (isset($part->disposition) && $part->disposition == 'ATTACHMENT');

    if ($part->ifdparameters) {
        foreach ($part->dparameters as $object) {
            if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                $is_attachment = true;
                $filename = $object->value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($part->ifparameters) {
        foreach ($part->parameters as $object) {
            if (strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                $is_attachment = true;
                $name = $object->value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$is_attachment) {
        continue;
    }
    
    $attachment = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $email_number, $email_number+1);

    if ($part->encoding == 3) {
        $attachment = base64_decode($attachment);
    } elseif ($part->encoding == 4) {
        $attachment = quoted_printable_decode($attachment);
    }

    $attachments[] = [
        'is_attachment' => $is_attachment,
        'filename' => isset($filename) ? $filename : '',
        'name' => isset($name) ? $name : '',
        'attachment' => isset($attachment) ? $attachment : ''
    ];
}


/* iterate through each attachment and save it */
$folder = "attachment";
if (!is_dir($folder)) {
         mkdir($folder);
    }

foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

    if (!empty($attachment['name'])) {
        $filename = $attachment['name'];
    } elseif (!empty($attachment['filename'])) {
        $filename = $attachment['filename'];
    } else {
        $filename = time().'.dat';
    }

    $destination = './'.$folder.'/'.$email_number.'-'.$filename;

    file_put_contents($destination, $attachment['attachment']);
}
```

- [count](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjht-PW6ZL0AhUeiv0HHdKGA-UQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.count.php&usg=AOvVaw3KsjTPPvjJQEzx71Zs_6uh) returns 1 (truthy) if input is falsy, so you should not use it inside comparisons in this way
- you does not need loop [for](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwisi-iA6pL0AhWu8rsIHSHWB3IQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fcontrol-structures.for.php&usg=AOvVaw0OuaqM_ZDgtqxg6AVBUDw_) when you can use [foreach](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwisi-iA6pL0AhWu8rsIHSHWB3IQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fcontrol-structures.foreach.php&usg=AOvVaw0PgGFIQpqDjm0XTsoQws-2): makes things simple
- add new item to array attachments only if it is actually useful: it does not make sense to add items that will be skipped later when saving
- foreach loops through iterables, and if count is 0 it simply does not loop: no need to check count before foreach
- no need to assign $filename and overwrite: just check with comparison, and assign directly the proper value or default case
- [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) is identical to calling [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fwrite()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fclose()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) successively to write data to a file
- more robust check on $is_attachment
- mkdir folder should stay outside the loop, as the folder is always the same

Answer (score -1):

```
    //may this help you...good luck
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');     
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');     
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
    set_time_limit(3000); 
    $fName = [];
    if ($subject=='xyz subject' || $subject=='xyz subject')$folder_name = $subject;
    else$folder_name = substr($subject,stripos($subject,':')+2);
    $list = glob('downloads/xyz/'.$folder_name.'/*');
    foreach($list as  $key => $filename){$explodeName = explode('/', $filename);$fName[] = $explodeName[2];}
    foreach($list as $file){if(is_file($file))unlink($file);}     

    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}Inbox';
    $username = 'xyz.xyz@xyz.com';
    $password = '*******************';

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());  
    $emails   = imap_search($inbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$subject.'"');
    foreach ($emails as $key => $value) {

        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$value,0);
        $message_date = new DateTime($overview[0]->date);
        $date = $message_date->format('Ymd');
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$value,2);
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $value);
        $attachments = [];
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                        'is_attachment' => false,
                        'filename' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                        'attachment' => ''
                    );
                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $value, $i+1);                           
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) //3 = BASE64 encoding
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) //4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach($attachments as $attachment)//iterate through each attachment and save it
            {
                if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
                {
                    $filename = $attachment['name'];                        
                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
                    if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";
                    $new_fileName = $date.'-'.$value.'-'.$filename;                        
                    if(!in_array($new_fileName, $fName))
                    {
                        $folder='./downloads/xyz/'.$folder_name.'/';
                        if(!is_dir($folder))mkdir($folder);
                        $fp = fopen("./". $folder ."/". $date . "-". $value."-". $filename, "w+");
                        fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                        fclose($fp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        imap_mail_move($inbox,$overview[0]->msgno,'xyz_label'); 
        imap_expunge($inbox); 

        /*  ->Always try to read/open the email by subject/or according to need
            ->Move or Delete Old/not required mail, so that u don't need to search/load lots of email
            ->Avoiding unnecessary and old email of the same subject , is to move/delete the same.
        */
    }
    imap_close($inbox);//Never forget to close the connection
```