# Getting all mails from Gmail using PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'my gmail id';
$password = 'my gmail password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

Problem is that first I get error like that **Cannot connect to Gmail: Too many login failures** and after I remove `/SSL` from `$hostname` that gives me error like **Cannot connect to Gmail: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)**.

I do all the thing related for connection like *enable pop3* and *Imap*, *Unlock Google account* and also *Turn on less secure apps*.

But, I can't find out what actual problem?

Comment: share what code related to **javascript, jQuery and php**? try something then come here to get help. i am afraid this question most probably going to be closed.

Comment: @Jai thanks for encourage me, i will try for getting emails from gmail but, i getting error every time. if you know about please help me, i change my question  for better know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not work because of i used ALL in imap_search so, that get lots of mail and unable to pass huge mail. After i changed code as per the search criteria for giving the limit and that's work fine

```
    ALL - return all messages matching the rest of the criteria
    ANSWERED - match messages with the \\ANSWERED flag set
    BCC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Bcc: field
    BEFORE "date" - match messages with Date: before "date"
    BODY "string" - match messages with "string" in the body of the message
    CC "string" - match messages with "string" in the Cc: field
    DELETED - match deleted messages
    FLAGGED - match messages with the \\FLAGGED (sometimes referred to as Important or Urgent) flag set
    FROM "string" - match messages with "string" in the From: field
    KEYWORD "string" - match messages with "string" as a keyword
    NEW - match new messages
    OLD - match old messages
    ON "date" - match messages with Date: matching "date"
    RECENT - match messages with the \\RECENT flag set
    SEEN - match messages that have been read (the \\SEEN flag is set)
    SINCE "date" - match messages with Date: after "date"
    SUBJECT "string" - match messages with "string" in the Subject:
    TEXT "string" - match messages with text "string"
    TO "string" - match messages with "string" in the To:
    UNANSWERED - match messages that have not been answered
    UNDELETED - match messages that are not deleted
    UNFLAGGED - match messages that are not flagged
    UNKEYWORD "string" - match messages that do not have the keyword "string"
    UNSEEN - match messages which have not been read yet
```

> PHP Code

```
$sinceDate = "31 December 2015";
$beforeDate = "06 January 2016"; 
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SINCE "'.$sinceDate.'" BEFORE"'.$beforeDate.'"' );
```

After i work on downloading attachment in directory using IMAP and its well work answer on [Downloading attachments to directory with IMAP in PHP, randomly works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649579/downloading-attachments-to-directory-with-imap-in-php-randomly-works/34593248#34593248)